# Why is this code with parallel programming slow?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-threads

I'm studying about parallel programming and testing this brute force code, to crack a password with 7 positions without and with parallelism, but when applying parallel programming, the code is running slower than before. Does anyone know why? How can I use parallel programming in this code to make it faster? thanks.

```
public class Worker extends Thread{

private static final int[] valuesCaracter = {48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48};
private static final int arraySize = valuesCaracter.length;
private static char[] symbols = new char[arraySize];
private static String password = null;

@Override
public void run() {
    generatePasswordCaracters();
}

public static int ajustaValor(int valueASCII) {
    return switch (valueASCII) {
        case 58 -> 65;
        case 91 -> 97;
        default -> valueASCII;
    };
}

public static String generatePasswordCaracters() {

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        while (valuesCaracter[i] <= 122) {

            

            for (int j = 0; j < symbols.length; j++) {
                symbols[j] = (char) valuesCaracter[j];

            }

            password = new String(symbols);

            System.out.println(password);

            valuesCaracter[6]++;

            for(int k = arraySize - 1; k >= 1; k--) {
                if (valuesCaracter[k] > 122) {
                    valuesCaracter[k - 1]++;
                    valuesCaracter[k] = 48;
                }  else {
                    valuesCaracter[k] = ajustaValor(valuesCaracter[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return password;
}
```

}

---

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.FileHeader;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Worker[] Workers =
                {new Worker(),
                new Worker(),
                new Worker(),
                new Worker(),
                new Worker(),
                new Worker()};

        for (Worker workerStart : Workers) {
            workerStart.start();
        }

        try {
            for (Worker workerJoin : Workers) {
                workerJoin.join();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("C:\\vsCodeProjects-Java\\BruteForce\\src\\file.zip"));
            if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {

                zipFile.setPassword(Worker.generatePasswordCaracters().toCharArray());
            }
            List<FileHeader> fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();

            for (FileHeader o : fileHeaderList) {

                zipFile.extractFile(o, "C:\\vsCodeProjects-Java\\BruteForce\\src");
                System.out.println("This is the password");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your workers are all doing exactly the same work, not different parts of the work.

Comment: IMHO your approach is completely broken. I'm not sure if `Worker.generatePasswordCaracters()` even stops. Have you tried to create all passwords with 3 characters? Then, if it stops: you create one last password using `Worker.generatePasswordCaracters()` and try to decrypt the zip file **once** with this last password. Not exactly what I understand as "brute-forcing zip file decryption". Then: are you sure that creating the passwords is the bottleneck? I would expect the file decryption to be the bottleneck - and it doesn't improve the overall speed if you optimize the wrong code path.

Comment: Lastly: `Worker` uses a bunch of static fields. If you want multiple thread to create passwords then you **must** synchronize the access to those static fields - which means that your threads will be blocking each other all the time.

Comment: My approach would be to create a synchronized method `createNextPassword()` that creates the next possible password and use several threads that each one repeatedly calls `createNextPassword()` to fetch a password and then tries to decrypt the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

This "parallel" code is being executed sequentially.

Main thread blocked at each step of iteration, wait for every worker to do its job. Javadoc says [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()):

> Waits for this thread to die.

So actually although this you've created multiple threads your code will be even slower than sequential execution because threads are not cheap.

Choose either: don't control the execution of your threads, or perform these tasks in a single thread.

**Sidenote:** implementing `Runnable` is more flexible than extending `Thread`. Because you can start a thread only once, but the same runnable task could be reused as many times as needed.

And if your goal to parallelize a single task, you might take a look at [ForkJoin framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html), which will allow splitting the task in to multiple. For that `Worker` class should extend either `RecursiveTask` or `RecursiveAction` and override method `compute()`.